# Understanding Spark async actions

Tags: java, apache-spark, asynchronous

I have a Java code for Spark:

```
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext("local","MyAppName", sparkConf);

    JavaPairRDD<String, String> wholeTextFiles1 = sc.wholeTextFiles("/path1/*");
    JavaPairRDD<String, String> wholeTextFiles2 = sc.wholeTextFiles("/path2/*");

    JavaFutureAction<Void> voidJavaFutureAction = wholeTextFiles1.foreachAsync(new VoidFunction<Tuple2<String, String>>() {
        public void call(Tuple2<String, String> stringStringTuple2) throws Exception {
            //do something
        }
    });

    JavaFutureAction<Void> voidJavaFutureAction1 = wholeTextFiles2.foreachAsync(new VoidFunction<Tuple2<String, String>>() {
        public void call(Tuple2<String, String> stringStringTuple2) throws Exception {
            //do something
        }
    });

    voidJavaFutureAction.get();
    voidJavaFutureAction1.get();
```

There is two `foreachAsync` actions. I'm waiting spark to do two different actions in the same time. But in spark application UI, I see 2 stages, but one of this waits for start until the other one finishes. I'm waiting to two different stages works same time, am I wrong? How `foreachAsync` works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How foreachAsync works?

You understand correctly, but should configure scheduler to use this feature

```
val conf = new SparkConf().
                 ...
                 .set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
```

See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application

> By default, Spark’s scheduler runs jobs in FIFO fashion.

Update

Check that you set properties correctly https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#viewing-spark-properties. 
Configure pools - http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#configuring-pool-properties

> I see 2 stages

It is about jobs/tasks. FAIR mode need to parallel jobs/tasks, which can be parallelized. Stages have dependencies, so they should be executed sequentially. See https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-dagscheduler.html

Could you show your DAG, pools?

Comment: Actually I added `spark.scheduler.mode=FAIR` line to `spark-defaults.conf` file, but stil works same.

Comment: @ahmetkamaran I recommend use this setting with context, not with default properties, 
because met differences. Anyway, at least check that you set properties correctly https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#viewing-spark-properties. Did you also configure pools http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#configuring-pool-properties?

Comment: Now I'm setting `spark.scheduler.mode` with context and still works same. Yes I have already configure pools. In application UI at Jobs tab I can see Scheduling mode as `FAIR` and stages tab pool name `production` and scheduling mode `FAIR`